# Image Texture does not appear (correctly)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, uv-image-editor

When modelling a smart phone I selected part of my mesh, create a uv map with  "project from view" and added an image texture. First the image texture was stretched and now it doesn't appear at all. [image] How can I have this image texture Front Camera.png correctly mapped on my mesh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image texture is not a shader, so it shouldn't be plugged to a mix shader node.

Use the image on the color part of the diffuse node.

[image]